# AssertionError: You cannot call `.save()` on a serializer with invalid data

Tags: django, django-views, pycharm

```
def update(self, request, pk=None):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    product = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
    serializer = ProductSerializer(product, data=request.data, context={"request": request})
    serializer.is_valid()
    serializer.save()
    # print(request.data["product_details"])
    for type_detail in request.data["product_details"]:
        if type_detail["id"] == 0:
            # For Insert New product_type Details
            del type_detail["id"]
            type_detail["product_id"] = serializer.data["id"]
            serializer2 = ProductDetailsSerializer(data=type_detail, context={"request": request})
            serializer2.is_valid()
            serializer2.save()
        else:
            # For Update product_type Details
            queryset2 = ProductDetails.objects.all()
            type_product = get_object_or_404(queryset2, pk=type_detail["id"])
            del type_detail["id"]
            serializer3 = ProductDetailsSerializer(type_product, data=type_detail, context={"request": request})
            serializer3.is_valid()
            serializer3.save()
            print("UPDATE")

    return Response({"error": False, "message": "Data Has Been Updated"})
```

hi guys I have got this error in my view set Django can you guys help me with it ..whenever I want to update the date this is the error I get

Answer (score 1):

It clearly shows that your serializer data validation failed. That is,

```
serializer.is_valid()
```

This returned false. And even after that you are saving serializer object which results in this error.

Ideally it should be like :

```
if serializer.is_valid()
    serializer.save()
```

Or much cleaner version to raise exception:

```
if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
    serializer.save()
```

You need to check why this serializer object is not valid. And then save the data if `serializer.is_valid()` returns True.